# Conditional probability from Joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm stuck at a question attached below

[image]

I'm confused at what is implied by $~Y=y~$, as $~y~$ is the limit. What do I substitute in the bottom while calculating the marginal probability. Do I integrate the numerator as well with $~y~$. Thank you

Just need to know what to do next, not the solution.

Comment: You need to find $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, where $f_Y(y) = \int f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dx$

Comment: What is the meaning of Y=y then

Comment: Your information. It is something like: Firstly you only know the density of random vector. Then someone come and tells you that second component is $y$. Now you know something, so this is reasonable to find new distribution based on your current information that $Y=y$, to better know what is it likely for $X$ to take values from certain set. To long story short: the formula is justifable from definition of conditional expectation and then finding distribution $/mathbb P(/cdot | Y)$. But if you don't want details,  the meaning is simply: which value of $y$ you need to put in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

First we compute the marginal distribution of $y$:
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dx = \int_{-1}^1 \left(x^2+\frac13y\right) = \frac23(1+y)\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y).
$$
Then we compute the conditional distribution of $X$ on $\{Y=y\}$:
$$
f_{X\mid Y=y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f(y)} = \frac{x^2+\frac13y}{\frac23(1+y)} = \frac{3x^2+y}{2(1+y)}\cdot 1_{(-1,1)\times(0,1)}(x,y).
$$